# Clap or Hi Hat? Whipping noise

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, synthesis

trying to see how to reproduce this sound that you here in this track.  They do it several times in the track and every other time it sounds quite different.  To me it sounds like a clap or hi hat with a short delay and massive reverb.   You can here it at 2:57.  There are two sounds in succession, the one that sounds like a clap and the other sort of sounds like a whip of some sort.  I've been experimenting with reversing the claps, but kinda wanna here everyone else opinion of that whip or whatever.

Comment: the video you attached is not available

Comment: I am able to play it fine.  You are not able to press play?

Comment: ah so... maybe it's restricted in Germany

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely a massive reverb, which is obscuring the source audio somewhat, but a clap sample is a good bet. I believe the variation between the different occurrences of the sound is the same sample being pitch-shifted, but to different degrees. I hear a clap, then this higher pitched "whip," then a lower pitched noisy knock, all part of a little motif in the beat that has it's own reverb bus :)  If the source audio is just a shifted clap sample, then there might be some narrow filter boosts on the different iterations of it or other effects to make those snapping and knocking qualities, and make the reverb ring really cut through the mix.  Instead of a filter, it could also be a layered sound recording of a knock, or a layered oscillator producing a tom-like knock.